# Is this a Bulkified trigger?

Tags: trigger, bulkification

This is a Trigger working properly where it will fetch Logo__c[Rich Text Area] From Parent Object(Account) and put in  Child Record(Contact) Logo__c[Again rich Text Area]

```
trigger Pop_Img on Contact (before Insert, before update) {

For(Contact con : Trigger.New){

   For(Account acc : [Select id, name , Img__c From Account Where Id =:con.accountId]){

     con.Img__c = acc.Img__c;
     system.debug(')))))))))))))))))))))))))'+acc.IMg__c);
     system.debug('(((((((((((((((((((('+con.IMg__c);

   }
  }
}
```

since it is before No need to any DML operation,but whether is it a Bulkified Trigger

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Bulkified trigger would look like this. (I did not check the exact syntax but hope that it gives you idea)

```
trigger Pop_Img on Contact (before Insert, before update) {

    List <id> acid = new list <ID>();

    Map <Id,String> accMap = new map<Id,String>();

    For(Contact con : Trigger.New) {
        acid.add(con.accountId)
    }

    for(Account acc =  [Select id, name , Img__c From Account Where Id in :acid]) {
        accMap.put(acc.ud, acc.Img__c)
    }

    For(Contact con : Trigger.New) {
         con.Img__c = accmap.get(con.accountId);
         system.debug(')))))))))))))))))))))))))'+accmap.get(con.accountId));
         system.debug('(((((((((((((((((((('+con.IMg__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a bulkified trigger.

Have a look inside the first loop on Contacts. What does it do for each contact in the trigger?

There can be up to 200 records in a trigger, so the loop will execute up to 200 times. The inner loop performs a query on Account. The limit on the number of SOQL queries is 100...